# Example code for "Gauge Invariance, Geometry and Arbitrage" paper

Tags: programming, arbitrage

This [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3043) describes an algorithm for computing arbitrage opportunites using a gauge connetion.

Has anyone written a python program or C++ or C# program that shows how to follow the steps outlines in the paper, and if so, could you point me to it?

Comment: no one will write a code for you unless you pay them....

Comment: He's not asking someone to write to code for him, he's asking if one has an implementation example to share. It's not really the same.